# How to implement Sphinx search engine in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, sphinx

I'am trying to implement Sphinx in my Symfony2 project. I read that I have to include sphinxapi.php file, but I do knot know how to use `include()` function in Symfony2.

Comment: Lots of examples on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=symfony2+include

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use include() to achieve this.
Create a service:

```
sphinxService:
    class: 'path\to\sphinxapi.php'
```

And in your controller, call it through container:

```
$sphinxApi = $this->container->get('sphinxService');
```

Comment: Where should I create service? Where should I upload file? Can I include all types of files this way?

Comment: In app/config/services.yml. You can include an external library in src/AppBundle/Helper for example, unless you find one on Github and use it with Composer (https://github.com/IAkumaI/SphinxsearchBundle)

Comment: I do not have Helper foder. So I have to create it? Am I right? Sorry for my trivial questions but it's new thing for me. My next question - what should I do if I want to include i.e single php file with piece of code i.e loop. Should I use the same solution too?

Comment: You have to create the folder. Yes, you can use the same solution.